# CFPDF create variable from a BLOB

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdocument, cfpdf

In ColdFusion 9 we have pdf data stored in a blob in the database.

How do I get that into a cfpdf variable?  It seems like all options require a filename.  Is there a way to do it without writing a file?

Answer (score 1):

`CFPDF` and `CFDOCUMENT` are for creating and modifying a PDF dynamically. As you already have the PDF in a blob in your database you simply need the CF page to send it back as part of the response using `CFCONTENT`. Assuming you are using some type of ID to reference which PDF you want to retrieve from your database an example would look like this:

```
<cfquery name="qryFile" datasource="MyDatasourceHere">
    SELECT id, name, data
    FROM files
    WHERE id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#URL.id#" />
</cfquery>
<cfheader name="content-length" value="#ArrayLen(qryFile.data)#" />
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#qryFile.name#" />
<cfcontent type="application/octet-stream" variable="#qryFile.data#" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to get it into a CFPDF variable though so that I can do some of the CFPDF actions on it as well.

Comment: Gotcha, if you don't want to stick it on your web server file system and you have ColdFusion 9 you can use the CF virtual file system and store the files in memory instead using ram://