# ColdFusion: Create PDF from multiple PDF blobs

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, cfpdf

I have multiple pdfs stored in my database as blobs and I need to merge them to create a single pdf that needs to be streamed to the user.

I understand that it is fairly easy to do this if I am rendering a single pdf from blob, but I cannot figure how to merge multiple blobs.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=#document.name#.#document.ext#">
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#document.content#">
```

I see that CFPDF helps with this functionality, but cant seem to be able to get my blob into a cfpdf variable. A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069717/cfpdf-create-variable-from-a-blob) before, but it doesnt have the answer I seek.

Thanks!

Comment: Also tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690548/coldfusion-cfpdf-reading-a-binary-database-column/10692761#10692761 but am getting the error:

An error occurred during the EXTRACTTEXT operation in the cfpdf tag.

Error: Invalid Document. Check your source or files in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the blob data to a file (in-memory using `ram://` if possible to save writing to disk) and then use that as the `cfpdf` merge source. You can do it for each blob as you loop over your query within the `cfpdf action="merge"` tag:

```
<cfquery name="q" datasource="test">
  SELECT content FROM pdfs
</cfquery>

<cfpdf action="merge" name="mergedPdf">
  <cfloop query="q">
    <cfset tempBinary=q.content><!---intermediate var seems to be necessary in some environments --->
    <cffile action="write" output="#tempBinary#" file="ram://temp.pdf">
    <cfpdfparam source="ram://temp.pdf">
  </cfloop> 
</cfpdf>
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#ToBinary( mergedPdf )#" reset="true">
```

Note you can use a single temp file - no need to create a different one for each blob in the query.

Comment: CfSimplicity, Thanks for this answer. I had to come back to this after a while and figured I hadnt solved this issue. You method worked, except for a minor correction. I have edited the code to include the update.

Comment: Glad to help. My original code works on CF9.0.1 without the intermediate variable for `q.content`. Which CF version are you using?

Comment: I am on cf 9.0.1 as well. I was getting an "error during MERGE" without the intermediate variable.

Comment: Strange. Perhaps a difference in HotFixes. Anyway the intermediate var also works in my environment so I've adjusted my code in case others have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following

Retrieve each pdf blob stored in db and create pdf using cfpdf and store them in some temp directory

```
  <cfpdf action="write" destination="c:\pdfs\1.pdf" source="#mypdfblob1" >
```

Retrieve all such blobs and store them as pdfs in the temp directory

Merge all those pdfs using cfpdf merge by specifying the temp directory in cfpdf merge

```
<cfpdf action="merge" directory="C:\pdfs" destination="C:\result.pdf">
```

Comment: Trying cfpdf write throws "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings."

Comment: can you provide some stacktrace

Comment: And adding a ToString to the blob didnt help either.

Comment: try dumping the variable #document.content#

Comment: Yep, that dumps the binary query object fine. Btw, trying to see if I can attach stacktrace.

Comment: using tostring also didn't help either seems like encoding issue. Which encoding have you been using while making the blob with the pdf content.